# Why is this object being released?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when releasing `newImage` on the last line of the following code snippet:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[self setImageToSave:newImage];
[newImage release];
```

I'm assuming that `newImage` is released with the call on the preceding line. If so, why is it being released in the `setImageToSave` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this line:

```
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

is creating an autoreleased object. In between that line and before this line:

```
[newImage release];
```

..it is getting autoreleased. You're trying to release an autoreleased (and already released) object is why you're getting that error. Remove the release. As for this line:

```
[self setImageToSave:newImage];
```

If you need to save newImage for any release you should retain either here or in the setImageToSave method. Remember, since you manually retained it you'll need to match it with a release at some point either within the same method or somewhere else.

Comment: Moreover, remember that in Cocoa world functions which does not contain world new/copy in methods return autoreleased objects.

Comment: Thank you so much Jordan. I changed it to `[self setImageToSave:[newImage retain]];` and then I release `[self imageToSave]` in a later method. Does this sound right?

Comment: You really should read the official Apple guide to memory management. Roughly, whatever you retain, you should match with a release. Whatever you init/copy/new you should match with a release. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: @Jordan: More precisely, it is `alloc` that needs to be balanced with a `release`, not `init`.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll check out the guide. Thanks again!